# Many predictors, small training sample $\rightarrow$ large variance, overfitting

Tags: estimation, references, overfitting, high-dimensional

If the number of predictors is relatively large compared to the available amount of training observation, the predicted parameters will have large variances. Moreover, this will likely cause the problem of overfitting.

The above statement makes intuitive sense: the lesser training observations we use to predict coefficients on average, the more unstable the estimates are.

Does anyone have a more technical (mathematical) explanation?
References would be appreciated as well.